# How to add a view that disappears when scroll up (go down in listview) and appears when scroll down?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I want to add a button to the bottom of the layout. When I scroll up, go down in the listview, I want the button to disappear and vice versa. Just like in the twitter app. There is a textView for quick tweet at the bottom of the home page and when scroll up the view becomes invisible. What is the most simple code doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,
create custom scroll class,

```
public class CustomScrollView extends ScrollView {

    private OnArrowChangeListener onArrowChangeListener = null;
    private int id = 0;

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        id = getId();
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        id = getId();
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        id = getId();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (getChildCount() == 0) {
            // no child
        } else {
            View view = (View) getChildAt(getChildCount() - 1);
            if (view == null) {
                super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
                return;
            }
            int diff = (view.getBottom() - (getHeight() + getScrollY() + view.getTop()));
            // Utility.log(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "@" + diff);
            if (diff <= 10) {
                // bottom reached
                if (onArrowChangeListener != null) {
                    onArrowChangeListener.onReachedBottom(id);
                }
            } else if (t <= 10) {
                // top reached
                if (onArrowChangeListener != null) {
                    onArrowChangeListener.onReachedTop(id);
                }
            } else {
                // middle
                if (onArrowChangeListener != null) {
                    onArrowChangeListener.onVisibleBoth(id);
                }
            }
        }

        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        // Utility.log(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "v ->" + t);
    }

    public OnArrowChangeListener getOnArrowChangeListener() {
        return onArrowChangeListener;
    }

    public void setOnArrowChangeListener(OnArrowChangeListener onArrowChangeListener) {
        this.onArrowChangeListener = onArrowChangeListener;
    }

    public void computeInitialScroll() {
        CustomScrollView.this.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (CustomScrollView.this.getChildCount() > 0) {
                    View view = CustomScrollView.this.getChildAt(0);
                    if (view != null) {
                        int amount = CustomScrollView.this.getMaxScrollAmount();
                        int height = view.getBottom() - view.getTop();
                        if (height < amount || getHeight() > height) {
                            if (onArrowChangeListener != null) {
                                onArrowChangeListener.onInVisibleBoth(id);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

put this in your XMl

```
 <com.app.ui.CustomScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" >
```

implement OnScrollListener on your activity or fragment,

private int pos = 0;
listview.setSelection(pos);

```
@Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pos = firstVisibleItem;
        int first = firstVisibleItem;
        int last = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;

        int adapterSize = totalItemCount;
        if (visibleItemCount >= adapterSize) {
            // Scroll center of items
            return;
        }

        if (first > 0 && last < adapterSize) {
            // middle
            // both visible
            btnUp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnDown.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return;
        }

        if (last == adapterSize) {
            //Scroll to bottom

            return;
        }

        if (first == 0) {
            //Scroll to top
            return;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html

and check `listView.getChildAt(0).getTop()` position every time you are scrolling.
if the difference between last top position and current top position is positive you are scrolling up. After that you can set a visibility of the button VISIBLE/INVISIBLE